# How can I extract list items using dictionary keys?

Tags: python

I have list and dictionary like this:

```
list_1 = ['if looks kill then i'm murdering]

dic_1 = {"kill": -2, "murdering": -3}
```

I want to extract list items that matches the dictionary key and append it to a set. 
I have two problems:
1. I cannot extract the list items that matches with key in the dictionary
2. How do I append list items to a set?

```
set_1 = set()
for items in list_1:
   list_1 = items.lower().split()

   for term in dic_1:

      forth_list = [words for words in list_1 if term != words]
      print forth_list
```

## This will print

```
['if', 'looks', 'then', 'i', 'm', 'murdering']
['if', 'looks', 'kill', 'then', 'i', 'm']

set_1.add(forth_list) # this produce a TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
print set_1
```

Comment: Why are you modifying `list_1` when looping over it? (`list_1 = items.lower().split()`)

Comment: Actually list_1 should be like this ['if looks kill then i'm murdering"].

Comment: what should be the result of running your algorithm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most efficient way to find what elements in the list are in a dictionary, is to use [dictionary views](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

```
set_1 |= dic_1.viewkeys() & list_1
```

A dictionary view such as returned by `dic_1.viewkeys()` is essentially a set, and by using `&` we take the intersection of that set and the list.

The `|=` syntax, using in-place OR, updates the set to add any elements found in the right-hand side not yet in the set.

Alternatively, you could use the [`set.update()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.update). The `.add()` method takes *one* element at a time instead, but you wanted to add all elements *in* the list to the set, not the list itself.

Demo:

```
>>> list_1 = "if looks kill then i'm murdering".split()
>>> dic_1 = {"kill": -2, "murdering": -3, "monty": 5}
>>> set_1 = set()
>>> set_1 |= dic_1.viewkeys() & list_1
>>> set_1
set(['murdering', 'kill'])
>>> set_1 |= dic_1.viewkeys() & "monty python's flying circus".split()
>>> set_1
set(['murdering', 'kill', 'monty'])
```

Comment: +1 Interesting solution. I have never seen people using ``|=`` syntax.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. Is there a way to get words not in dic_1 also in a separate set?

Comment: @user690462: use `set(list_1) - dic_1` to get the difference (all elements in `list_1` not in `dic_1`)

Answer (score 3):

The direct pythonic one-liner translation of what you're describing is:

```
set_1 = set(val for val in list_1.split() if val in dic_1)
```

It takes each value from the split, checks if that value is a key in dictionary and constructs a set out of those values using a generator expression.

Comment: This won't *update* the `set_1` set; it will create a new set instead. That is certainly what the OP was doing, but I understood that multiple lists are going to be added in a loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, in that case there's no way around the in-place update

Comment: Otherwise, your version is functionally equivalent as my version; I suspect mine is going to win out on speed as the list loop and set object creation is handled entirely in C instead of in a generator expression.

Comment: If you were to use `|=` you can dispense with the `set(..)` call though; the `.update()` method and it's `.__ior__()` alias take any sequence, not just sets.

Comment: This is also a good solution, but I am going to go with Martijn Pieters's answer as it is easier to update the set and that's what I wanted. I have voted up your answer.

Comment: @user690462 I'd go for Martijn's one too in this case.